# Difference between [h] and [H] in float position

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm trying to choose the positions of my tables but I can't figure out the difference between `[H]` and `[h]`. I've seen both advised over my search. If I use `[h]` the row spacing is different than `[H]` use.

Comment: For the long answer, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/4012, in particular the section _"Here" really just means "here if it fits"_.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Never use `[h]` on its own, it is basically an error waiting to happen and LaTeX will most likely give a warning and change it to `[ht]`.

LaTeX has four *float areas* into which a float may be placed: top of page (`t`), bottom of page (`b`), `here` where the float appears in the source (`h`) and on a float page with only floats and no text (`p`).

`H` makes the environment essentially not a float at all it is more or less the same as using `minipage` except that `\caption` works, but you can caption minipages using the `capt-of` package.

`H` should be used sparingly, like any large box, it is likely to produce bad page breaks with large amounts of white space.

If you use the optional argument of a float you are mostly *restricting* the float areas to which the float may be allocated. If you over-restrict it is likely that the float can not be positioned at all, and will then go to the end of the document. So if you want to allow `h` it is best to allow `t` and `p` as well so use `[tph]`. You should almost always use `p` if you use the optional argument.

Comment: Does the order of the letters in [tph] matter?

Comment: @Diaa no, latex has a fixed algorithm for placing floats and the option is just a filter that makes it skip stages, so if the option doesn't contain `t` latex doesn't try a top float If it has a `t` then it will try that, the order doesn't matter.