# How to add tables to a list?

Tags: tables, itemize

I would like to have these two tables as items of this list. Currently they are appearing outside the list, on the top of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%% problem

  \begin{itemize}
    \item item1
    \item item2
    \begin{table}
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|ll}
        + & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{adicao}
    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|ll}
        . & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{mult}
    }
    \end{table}

  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I have been searching about how to do it, however, until now I've only found how to do the opposite (how to insert lists in tables).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `table` environment is a float, and float placement [is handled in a very particular way by LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/32888). You can use the package `float`, which gives a float placement option, `H`, that essentially causes the float to no longer be treated as a float.

<sup>(Shameless self promotion: see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142334/32888) to [Is there any way to shift two \includegraphics images? Having trouble with \begin{figure}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142150/is-there-any-way-to-shift-two-includegraphics-images-having-trouble-with-begi/) for a discussion about the different possible parameters for float placement in LaTeX.)</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

    \item item 1

    \item item 2

        \begin{table}[H]
        \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|ll}
        + & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Adição}
        }
        \hfill
        \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|ll}
        . & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Multiplicação}
        }

        \end{table}

    \item item 3

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]