# How can I place a figure at a desired location while maintaining automatic captioning and cross-referencing?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, positioning

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}
\subsection{Hello World}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw=black,minimum size=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Circle}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}

\pagebreak

\subsection{Hello Human}
Figure \ref{fig} demonstrates a large circle.

\end{document}
```

Here is how the first page of the output looks like:[image]

The figure has floated to the top. Is there a way I can ensure that the figure remains below section 1.1 while still be able to generate captions with figure numbers automatically and use them for cross-referencing?

Comment: `\begin{figure}[htb]` ... should help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the float package and use [H] with your figure enviroment.

```
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommend to use `[H]`, it destroy float mechanism and consequently in cases, when is not enough space for image on a page, move image to the next page and left ugly white space on previous one.

Comment: Is there any difference between `h` and `H`? Is it case-insensitive?

Comment: @LoneLearner In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132106/difference-between-h-and-h-in-float-position) you can find information about the difference. :-) And yes, both are completely different parameters.