# Position of tables

Tags: tables

I have the following file containing my tables. The preamble is the one given by the journal I am going to send my paper:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\makeatletter\if@twocolumn\PassOptionsToPackage{switch}{lineno}\else\fi\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsbsy,amssymb,tabulary,graphicx,times,caption,fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=6.5in,margin=2cm,headsep=.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewenvironment{abstract} {\vspace*{-1pc}\trivlist\item[]\leftskip\oupIndent\hrulefill\par\vskip4pt\noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\mbox{\null}\\}{\par\noindent\hrulefill\endtrivlist} 
\linespread{1.13} \date{}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=sc,skip=1.4pt,aboveskip=1pc}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sc,skip=1.4pt,labelsep=newline}

\makeatletter\def\oupIndent{1pt}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{\hskip-\dimexpr(\tabcolsep)\hskip\oupIndent\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\oupIndent}{\centering\bfseries#1}}}
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{\centering\bfseries\ifx\@articleType\@empty\else\@articleType\\\fi#1}}
\let\@articleType\@empty \def\articletype#1{\gdef\@articleType{{\normal\itshape#1}}}

\makeatother

\tolerance=400
\usepackage{url,multirow,morefloats,floatflt,cancel,tfrupee}
\makeatletter

\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{textcomp}{}{\usepackage{textcomp}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[nointegrals]{wasysym}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\urlstyle{rm}
\makeatletter

%%%For Table column width calculation.
\def\mcWidth#1{\csname TY@F#1\endcsname+\tabcolsep}

%%Hacking center and right align for table
\def\cAlignHack{\rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue\parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}
\def\rAlignHack{\rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}

%Etal definition in references
\@ifundefined{etal}{\def\etal{\textit{et~al}}}{}

%\if@twocolumn\usepackage{dblfloatfix}\fi
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex\else\if@twocolumn\@ifpackageloaded{stfloats}{}{\usepackage{dblfloatfix}}\fi\fi

\AtBeginDocument{
\expandafter\ifx\csname eqalign\endcsname\relax
\def\eqalign#1{\null\vcenter{\def\\{\cr}\openup\jot\m@th
  \ialign{\strut$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil&$\displaystyle{{}##}$\hfil
      \crcr#1\crcr}}\,}
\fi
}

%For fixing hardfail when unicode letters appear inside table with endfloat
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}%
   {\renewcommand\efloat@iwrite[1]{\immediate\expandafter\protected@write\csname efloat@post#1\endcsname{}}}{\newif\ifefloat@tables}%
}%

\def\BreakURLText#1{\@tfor\brk@tempa:=#1\do{\brk@tempa\hskip0pt}}
\let\lt=<
\let\gt=>
\def\processVert{\ifmmode|\else\textbar\fi}
\let\processvert\processVert

\@ifundefined{subparagraph}{
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{2\parindent}{0ex plus 0.1ex minus 0.1ex}%
{0ex}{\normalfont\small\itshape}}%
}{}

% These are now gobbled, so won't appear in the PDF.
\newcommand\role[1]{\unskip}
\newcommand\aucollab[1]{\unskip}
  
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleX}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleX{1}}{}
\@ifundefined{tsGraphicsScaleY}{\gdef\tsGraphicsScaleY{.9}}{}
% To automatically resize figures to fit inside the text area
\def\checkGraphicsWidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \tsGraphicsScaleX\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}

\def\checkGraphicsHeight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>.9\textheight
    \tsGraphicsScaleY\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}

\def\fixFloatSize#1{}%\@ifundefined{processdelayedfloats}{\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#1}}\ifnum\wd0<\columnwidth\relax\renewenvironment{figure*}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}\fi}{}}
\let\ts@includegraphics\includegraphics

\def\inlinegraphic[#1]#2{{\edef\@tempa{#1}\edef\baseline@shift{\ifx\@tempa\@empty0\else#1\fi}\edef\tempZ{\the\numexpr(\numexpr(\baseline@shift*\f@size/100))}\protect\raisebox{\tempZ pt}{\ts@includegraphics{#2}}}}

%\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth]{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[{\ts@includegraphics}{\ts@includegraphics[width=\checkGraphicsWidth,height=\checkGraphicsHeight,keepaspectratio]}}}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\def\URL#1#2{\@ifundefined{href}{#2}{\href{#1}{#2}}}

%%For url break
\def\UrlOrds{\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds}

\edef\fntEncoding{\f@encoding}
\def\EUoneEnc{EU1}
\makeatother
\def\floatpagefraction{0.8} 
\def\dblfloatpagefraction{0.8}
\def\style#1#2{#2}
\def\xxxguillemotleft{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotleft}
\def\xxxguillemotright{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\guillemotright}

\newif\ifmultipleabstract\multipleabstractfalse%
\newenvironment{typesetAbstractGroup}{}{}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%%
% Tables
%%%%%

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, siunitx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[referable,para]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{amsmath,ragged2e} % <-- new
\usepackage{interval,pbox}
\usepackage{float}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}, table-format=1.3, table-space-text-post=***, 
table-number-alignment =center}
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}
{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\hyphenation{bur-kina}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand\Quad[1][1]{\foreach \Quaddy in {1,...,#1}{\quad}\ignorespaces}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sc,skip=1.4pt,labelsep=newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Replication of Table 2 in Tabellini (2010) \label{tabellini}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule \toprule
                                            &\mc{(1)}                   &\mc{(2)}                       &\mc{(3)}                   &\mc{(4)}                   &\mc{(5)}                   &\mc{(6)}                   &\mc{(7)}\\
\midrule
school                              &0.491\sym{***} &0.785\sym{***}     &0.374\sym{*}       &0.769\sym{***} &0.510\sym{***} &0.376\sym{*}       &0.523\sym{**} \\
                                        &(0.146)                    &(0.172)                        &(0.200)                    &(0.233)                    &(0.170)                    &(0.198)                    &0.244         \\
urb\_rate1850               &0.616\sym{***} &0.712\sym{***}     &0.615\sym{***} &0.708\sym{***} &0.805\sym{***} &0.616\sym{***} &0.741\sym{***}\\
                                        &(0.174)                    &(0.168)                        &(0.160)                    &(0.198)                    &(0.206)                    &(0.205)                    &0.151         \\
pc\_culture                     &0.578\sym{***} &                               &                           &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
                                        &(0.119)                    &                               &                           &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
pc\_culture\_pos                &                           &0.707\sym{***}     &                           &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
                                        &                           &(0.150)                        &                           &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
pc\_children                    &                               &                               &0.572\sym{***} &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
                                        &                           &                               &(0.186)                    &                           &                           &                           &                     \\
control                             &                           &                               &                           &1.359                  &                           &                           &                     \\
                                        &                           &                               &                           &(0.828)                    &                           &                           &                     \\
trust                                   &                           &                               &                           &                           &0.925\sym{**}      &                           &                     \\
                                        &                           &                               &                           &                           &(0.384)                    &                            &                     \\
obedience                       &                           &                               &                           &                           &                           &-0.929\sym{**}     &                     \\
                                        &                           &                               &                           &                           &                           &(0.456)                    &                     \\
respect                             &                           &                               &                           &                           &                           &                           &1.643\sym{***}\\
                                        &                               &                               &                           &                           &                           &                           &(0.512)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)                               &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                    &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}         \\[1ex]
Moran p--value              &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.000]}               &\mc{[0.004]}           &\mc{[0.015]}           &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.028]}           &\mc{[0.001]} \\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{{\it{Notes}:} The table replicates the estimation contained in Table 2 of Tabellini (2010). Robust standard errors are in the brackets. At the bottom of the table the p--values associtated to the Moran's I tests are reported in []. The null hypothesis of the test is the absence of a spatial dependence in the residuals. The tests are based on the on the usage of a spatial matrix, $\mathbf{W}$, which elements are the inverse of the distance between region $i$ and $j$, $\frac{1}{w_{ij}}$.\\
      *** $p<0.01$\\
      **{\phantom{*}} $p<0.05$ \\
      *{\phantom{**}} $p<0.10$ }\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimation of the SARAR (1,1) model \label{sarardW}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule \toprule
                                        &\mc{(1)}                   &\mc{(2)}                   &\mc{(3)}                   &\mc{(4)}                   &\mc{(5)}                           &\mc{(6)}                   &\mc{(7)}\\
\midrule         
school                          &0.424\sym{**}      &0.680\sym{***} &0.306\sym{*}       &0.617\sym{**}      &0.361                              &0.322                  &0.405\sym{**}\\
                                    &(0.185)                    &(0.210)                    &(0.182)                    &(0.245)                    &(0.242)                            &(0.212)                    &(0.180)              \\
urb\_rate1850           &0.563\sym{***} &0.650\sym{***} &0.524\sym{***} &0.582\sym{***} &0.700\sym{***}         &0.565\sym{***} &0.619\sym{***}\\
                                    &(0.141)                    &(0.126)                    &(0.139)                    &(0.161)                    &(0.171)                            &(0.184)                    &(0.123)                 \\
pc\_culture                 &0.497\sym{***} &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
                                    &(0.108)                    &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
pc\_culture\_pos        &                           &0.658\sym{***} &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
                                    &                           &(0.118)                    &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
pc\_children                &                           &                           &0.494\sym{***} &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &(0.171)                    &                           &                                   &                           &                     \\
control                         &                           &                           &                           &1.381\sym{**}      &                                   &                           &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &(0.688)                    &                                   &                           &                     \\
trust                               &                           &                           &                           &                           &0.969\sym{***}         &                           &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &(0.313)                            &                           &                     \\
obedience                   &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &-0.505                     &                     \\
                                &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &(0.448)                    &                     \\
respect                         &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &1.663\sym{***}\\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &(0.390)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)                           &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                        &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}     \\
$\zeta$                         &\mc{0.314}             &\mc{0.323}             &\mc{0.396}             &\mc{0.516}             &\mc{0.430}                     &\mc{0.469}             &   \mc{0.431}  \\
                                        &\mc{[0.040]}           &\mc{[0.021]}           &\mc{[0.010]}           &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.006]}                   &\mc{[0.006]}           &\mc{[0.002]}\\
$\rho$                          &\mc{-1.924}            &\mc{-2.158}            &\mc{-1.865}            &\mc{-1.655}            &\mc{-1.820}                    &\mc{-1.506}            &\mc{-2.209}\\
                                        &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.003]}           &\mc{[0.000]}                   &\mc{[0.009]}           &\mc{[0.000]}   \\
Wald test                       &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.001]}                &\mc{[0.003]}          &\mc{ [0.000]}      \\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{{\it{Notes}:} The Table reports the estimations of the SARAR model in Eqs. (2) and (3). Analysis is performed using the spatial matrix, $\mathbf{W}$, which elements are the inverse of the distance between region $i$ and $j$, $\frac{1}{w_{ij}}$. Standard errors, reported in ( ), are robust to heteroskedasticity. P--values of the significance of the tests on $\zeta$ and $\rho$ and their joint significance are in [ ].   \\
      *** $p<0.01$\\
      **{\phantom{*}} $p<0.05$ \\
      *{\phantom{**}} $p<0.10$ }\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\pagebreak

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Direct, indirect and total impact of culture on economic development  \label{DIT}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule \toprule
                                                        \Quad[6] &\mc{pc\_culture}  &\mc{pc\_culture\_pos}  &\mc{pc\_children}  &\mc{control}       &\mc{trust}             &\mc{obedience}     &\mc{respect}\\
\midrule
Direct                                                                  &0.498\sym{***} &0.661\sym{***}             &0.497\sym{***}     &1.397\sym{**}  &0.976\sym{***} &-0.509                         &1.676\sym{***}             \\
                                                                            &(0.107)                        &(0.118)                                    &(0.171)                            &(0.693)                    &(0.315)                        &(0.450)                            &(0.388)                                    \\
Indirect                                                                &   0.198                           &0.274\sym{*}                       &0.282\sym{**}          &1.265                      &0.633                          &-0.385                         &1.090\sym{**}                  \\
                                                                            &(0.125)                        &(0.161)                                    &(0.161)                            &(0.889)                    &(0.439)                        &(0.354)                            &(0.518)                                    \\      
Total                                                                   &0.697\sym{***} &0.934\sym{***}             &0.779\sym{***}     &2.662\sym{*}       &1.609\sym{**}      &-0.895                         &2.765\sym{***}             \\
                                                                            &(0.154)                        &0.193                                      &(0.250)                            &(1.381)                    &(0.642)                        &(0.750)                            &(0.613)                                    \\                                                                      
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{The Table decomposes the total effect of culture on economic development. The direct effect coincides with the coefficients reported in Table 2. \\
       *** $p<0.01$\\
      **{\phantom{*}} $p<0.05$ \\
      *{\phantom{**}} $p<0.10$ }\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\pagebreak

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.5pt}
\centering
\normalsize
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Estimation of the SARAR (1,1) model \label{sarardW}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{8}{d{2.5}}}
\toprule \toprule
                                        &\mc{(1)}                   &\mc{(2)}                   &\mc{(3)}                   &\mc{(4)}                   &\mc{(5)}                           &\mc{(6)}                   &\mc{(7)}
&\mc{(8)}\\
\midrule         
school                          &0.433\sym{**}      &0.495\sym{***} &0.821\sym{***} &0.350\sym{*}       &0.646\sym{**}              &0.401\sym{*}       &0.366\sym{*}           &0.493\sym{***}\\
                                    &(0.188)                    &(0.185)                    &(0.225)                    &(0.185)                    &(0.287)                            &(0.230)                    &(0.209)                        &(0.185)                \\
urb\_rate1850           &0.548\sym{***} &0.602\sym{***} &0.720\sym{***} &0.512\sym{***} &0.600\sym{***}         &0.733\sym{***} &0.608\sym{***}     &0.648\sym{***}\\
                                    &(0.142)                    &(0.141)                    &(0.124)                    &(0.134)                    &(0.161)                            &(0.175)                    &(0.203)                        &(0.116)                \\
pc\_culture                 &0.612\sym{***} &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
                                    &(0.121)                    &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
pc\_cultcond                &                           &0.538\sym{***} &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
                                &                           &(0.144)                    &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
pc\_culposcon           &                           &                           &0.739\sym{***} &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &(0.143)                    &                           &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
pc\_childcond               &                           &                           &                           &0.538\sym{***} &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &(0.183)                    &                                   &                           &                               &                     \\
control\_cond               &                           &                           &                           &                           &1.342                          &                           &                               &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &(1.015)                            &                           &                               &                     \\
trust\_cond                 &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &0.901\sym{**}      &                               &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &(0.378)                    &                               &                     \\
obcond                          &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &-0.186                         &                     \\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &(0.555)                        &                     \\
respect\_cond           &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &1.981\sym{***}\\
                                    &                           &                           &                           &                           &                                   &                           &                               &(0.339)         \\
\midrule
\(N\)                           &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}                        &\mc{69}                &\mc{69}     \\
$\zeta$                         &\mc{0.314}             &\mc{0.323}             &\mc{0.396}             &\mc{0.516}             &\mc{0.430}                     &\mc{0.469}             &   \mc{0.431}  \\
                                        &\mc{[0.040]}           &\mc{[0.021]}           &\mc{[0.010]}           &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.006]}                   &\mc{[0.006]}           &\mc{[0.002]}\\
$\rho$                          &\mc{-1.924}            &\mc{-2.158}            &\mc{-1.865}            &\mc{-1.655}            &\mc{-1.820}                    &\mc{-1.506}            &\mc{-2.209}\\
                                        &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.003]}           &\mc{[0.000]}                   &\mc{[0.009]}           &\mc{[0.000]}   \\
Wald test                       &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.001]}           &\mc{[0.000]}           &\mc{[0.001]}                &\mc{[0.003]}          &\mc{ [0.000]}      \\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
      \item[]{{\it{Notes}:} The Table reports the estimations of the SARAR model in Eqs. (2) and (3). Analysis is performed using the spatial matrix, $\mathbf{W}$, which elements are the inverse of the distance between region $i$ and $j$, $\frac{1}{w_{ij}}$. Standard errors, reported in ( ), are robust to heteroskedasticity. P--values of the significance of the tests on $\zeta$ and $\rho$ and their joint significance are in [ ].   \\
      *** $p<0.01$\\
      **{\phantom{*}} $p<0.05$ \\
      *{\phantom{**}} $p<0.10$ }\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I cannot figure out why table 3 is reported after table 4. Any hint on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can use `[!htbp]` instead of [H] to make the table appear where it is in the document [here,top,bottom,page]. Furthermore your table 3 has not such an argument. So write `\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]`. Then it should work.

[Here](http://web.mit.edu/molly/Public/mini/figtab.pdf) you have a short overview about table and figure enviroments.

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132106/difference-between-h-and-h-in-float-position) you can find an explanation between the difference of `[h]` and `[H]`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine.